# how to delete uploaded file from krajee fileupload plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

uploading is working, delete is not working, url is correct.
delete method is not triggering while click on delete button newly uploaded file 
my js code is:

```
$("#input-700").fileinput({
            uploadUrl: "/Account/UploadFiles", // server upload action
            uploadAsync: false,
            maxFileSize: 1000,
            maxFileCount: 5,
            uploadExtraData: function () {
                return {
                    company_mst_pk: '1',
                    user_mst_pk:'1'
                };
            },
            fileType: "any",
            overwriteInitial: false,
            initialPreviewAsData: true,
            initialPreview: [
            "http://localhost:49589/Uploads/_1ddChrysanthemum.jpg",
            "http://localhost:49589/Uploads/_1ddLighthouse.jpg",
            "http://localhost:49589/Uploads/1dd_Penguins.jpg",
            ],
            initialPreviewConfig: [
            { caption: "transport-1.jpg", size: 329892, width: "120px", url: "/Account/DeleteCV", key: 1 },
            { caption: "transport-2.jpg", size: 872378, width: "120px", url: "/Account/DeleteCV", key: 2 },
            { caption: "transport-3.jpg", size: 632762, width: "120px", url: "/Account/DeleteCV", key: 3 },
            ],
            deleteUrl: "/Account/DeleteCV",
            deleteExtraData: function () {
                return {
                    company_mst_pk: '1',
                    user_mst_pk: '1'
                };
            },
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your file you have to answer in json like this

```
{"initialPreview":["https://placeimg.com/800/460/animals/1"],"initialPreviewAsData":true,"initialPreviewConfig":[{"caption":"Animal-1.jpg","size":732762,"width":"120px","url":"/site/file-delete","key":1}]}
```

There is more info http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/6